issue with saving and publishing Power Apps custom form
I'm hoping I'm not the only one encountering difficulties saving and publishing Power Apps custom forms. Despite Power Apps showing no errors during the save and publish process, the form remains unchanged in SharePoint, and the previous version still opens up. I even checked the version history of the form, but there hasn't been a new version in the past 8 months. I've tried clearing the browser cache and using other browsers, but nothing seems to work.
Could anyone please assist with resolving this issue?
